# kalman filter for a multifactor model in R

Tags: returns, factor-models, performance-evaluation, kalman, factor-loading

I am trying to set up a time varying factor model for the purpose of return decomposition via kalman filter.

Following this [example](http://lalas.github.io/quantitativeThoughts/r/2014/09/01/dlmTutorial.html#topic4.1) and slightly modifying it so as to accommodate for more than one input parameters (i.e S&P 500, Equity L/S index etc) I am getting the betas for the two benchmarks but, as expected, they don't necessarily sum up to 1.

Is there any way to add a constraint during the MLE that the output parameters have to sum up to one?

**EDIT**...adding the code below, it's basically the same code as in the [example](http://lalas.github.io/quantitativeThoughts/r/2014/09/01/dlmTutorial.html#topic4.1) with just adding another index and removing the intercept(alpha)

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics, quietly = TRUE,  warn.conflicts = FALSE)

data(managers)
# extract HAM1 and SP500 excess returns
HAM1 = 100*(managers[,"HAM1", drop=FALSE] - managers[,"US 3m TR", drop=FALSE])
factor_indices = cbind(100*(managers[,"SP500 TR", drop=FALSE] - managers[,"US 3m TR", drop=FALSE]),100*(managers[,"EDHEC LS EQ", drop=FALSE]))
factor_indices= factor_indices['1997-01-31/']
HAM1 = HAM1['1997-01-31/']
colnames(factor_indices) = c("SP500","EQLS")

# Specifying a set model parameters
s2_v = 1      # Variance of observations
s2_sp = 0.01 
s2_eqls = 0.01  
# Construct a regression model
tvp.dlm = dlmModReg(X=factor_indices, addInt=FALSE, dV=s2_v, dW=c(s2_sp, s2_eqls))

# looking at the various component
tvp.dlm[c("FF","V","GG","W","m0","C0")]
tvp.dlm[c("JFF","JV","JGG","JW")]

ols.fit = lm(HAM1 ~ factor_indices)
summary(ols.fit)

start.vals = c(1,0.01,0.01)

names(start.vals) = c("lns2_v", "lns2_sp", "lns2_eqls")

# function to build Time Varying Parameter state space model
buildTVP <- function(parm, x.mat){
  parm <- exp(parm)
  return( dlmModReg(X=x.mat, dV=parm[1],addInt=FALSE, dW=c(parm[2], parm[3])) )
}

# Estimate the model
TVP.mle = dlmMLE(y=HAM1, parm=start.vals, x.mat=factor_indices, build=buildTVP, hessian=T)

# get sd estimates
#se2 <- sqrt(exp(TVP.mle$par))
#names(se2) = c("s_obs", "s_alpha", "s_beta")
#sqrt(se2)

TVP.dlm <- buildTVP(TVP.mle$par, factor_indices)
TVP.f <- dlmFilter(y = HAM1, mod = TVP.dlm)
# Optimal estimates of θ_t given information available at time T.
TVP.s <- dlmSmooth(TVP.f)

# extract smoothed states 
sp.s = xts(TVP.s$s[-1,1,drop=FALSE], as.Date(rownames(TVP.s$s[-1,])))
eqls.s  = xts(TVP.s$s[-1,2,drop=FALSE], as.Date(rownames(TVP.s$s[-1,])))
colnames(sp.s) = "sp"
colnames(eqls.s)  = "eqls"
```

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: sure, added above

Comment: While trying to reproduce the results given in lalas blog I stumbled upon following from the `dlm` reference manual: `Only **univariate** regression is currently covered`. But you are trying to run a multivariate regression. Were you aware of this?

Comment: I noticed that, but I think that I am trying to run a multiple (or multivariable) regression, there is a discussion about the terminology in this link https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2358/explain-the-difference-between-multiple-regression-and-multivariate-regression

Comment: Well, you seem to have 2 independent variables instead of 1.

Comment: Anyway, if you want the parameters (beta?) to sum to 1, I think you will have to modify this line: `dW=c(parm[2], parm[3]))` to `dW=c(parm[2], 1))`, which means leave `intercept` as it is, but equate the beta (`parm[3]`) to 1. I have played around and was able to increase the original value of `0.23528` to around `1.2`.

Comment: I may be confused but the dimension of my 'y' argument (following lalas' notation) is one so I only have one independent variable (HAM1)? The reason I don't want the intercept is because my target is to get a relationship of 
  HAM1 = beta1*SP + beta2*EQLS , whereby beta1+beta2 = 1

Comment: `y` aka `HAM1` is your dependent variable. `SP` and `EQLS` are your independents.

Comment: sorry, notation confusion.. but it's still the case that if my problem has two independent variables and one dependent it's not a multivariate one so it should be supported by the package.

Comment: I didn't check, I just found it out while reading the manual. Can you post the results if you tried the multivariate case?

Comment: I see. I was just pointing out that my problem is not a multivariate one just to reply to your initial hint that the package might not support what I am trying to do.

Comment: I mean if the package doesn't handle the multivariate case, how are your going to set your constraints for multiple betas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60121/discussion-between-sen-saven-and-ak88).

Comment: An interesting problem.  It seems to be possible as a number of papers reference linearly contained Kalman Filter solutions.  However, none of the ones I read seem to have published Python code.   The closest I found was KF https://pythonhosted.org/KF/ which seems to indicate they have a implemented solution in their docs, but the docs are rough.  Please answer your own question if you find a solution.  I'm very curious.